# Sending Text data to Google Drive from Javascript

Tags: google-drive-api

Is it possible to send data from the JavaScript to the  Google Drive . I am trying to send my local storage datas to the google drive.

Kindly suggest me a solution for the same.

Comment: Yes it is possible. Do you have a follow up question?

Comment: See this blog post: http://googleappsdeveloper.blogspot.nl/2012/09/introducing-javascript-support-for.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Google Drive SDK documentation includes a complete JavaScript quickstart guide that shows how to upload a file to Drive from JavaScript:

https://developers.google.com/drive/quickstart

It should be pretty straightforward to edit the sample code to use local storage instead of the file uploaded from a form.